# Is there a way to style multiple borders on Doughnut chart with Chart.js library?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

Here is my chart:
[image]
And here is the chart I need:
 [image]
The difference is that first chart doesn't have borders but second has 2 of them: white and gray
These are the options I use:

```
let activityTypeChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("pie-chart-activity-type-widget"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Average Duration of Each Task Type",
            backgroundColor: colors,
            data: GetActivityTypeCounters(),
        }],
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: false,
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index] || '';
                    return label;
                }
            }
        },
        cutoutPercentage: 65,
        hover: {
            onHover: function(e, a) {
                $("#activity-type-widget").css("cursor", a[0] ? "pointer" : "default");
            }
        }
    },
});
```

If I try to use border, borderWidth, etc., the border actually has only 1 color. Is there a way to set 2 or more borders, maybe using gradient somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't receive an answer so far, I allow myself to propose a solution that works  in case your chart is of a fixed size. This is far from being a perfect solution but the user won't notice the rather weird code behind.

You can fake the outer and inner borders by defining additional datasets as shown in the code snippet below.

```js
new Chart("myChart", {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [1, 1, 1],
      borderColor: "#CCCCCC",
      backgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"], // required for correct legend colors
      weight: 0.01,
      borderWidth: 1
    }, 
    {
      data: [1],
      backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
      hoverBackgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
      weight: 0.1,
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      data: [200, 100, 25],
      backgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"],
    },  
    {
      data: [1],
      backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
      hoverBackgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
      weight: 0.1,
      borderWidth: 0
    },
      {
      data: [1, 1, 1],
      borderColor: "#CCCCCC",
      weight: 0.03,
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true
    },
    tooltips: {
      filter: tooltipItem => tooltipItem.datasetIndex == 2
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```